# C'est quoi un livre blanc ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, mots-composés

Je me demande ce qu'est un livre blanc et pourquoi on l'appelle ainsi. Le mot composé a été utilisé dans un contexte technique.

Est-ce que le pluriel est « livres blancs » ?

Comment: Le pluriel est bien "livre blanc", et pour le reste, c'est l'équivalent de l'anglais "white paper". Wikipédia a un article dessus, et il existe en plusieurs langues : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_paper

Comment: Vous pensez que je devrais supprimer cette question ?

Comment: Pourquoi supprimer la question ? Cela peut servir à d'autres personnes... Par contre, il peut-être intéressant de préciser le contexte... Car pour moi (inculte), une livre blanc est un livre de couleur blanche, et donc je suis tenté de répondre qu'on l'appelle ainsi parce qu'il est blanc... :)

Comment: @Kyrio Are you sure that it's invariable in the plural? I've seen it as "livres blancs", but now I'm not sure.

Comment: My bad. I thought I had put the two S :-) it is indeed "livres blancs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je pense que la définition fournie sur Wikipedia est suffisante pour répondre quant au sens de cette expression:

> Un livre blanc est un recueil d'informations objectives et factuelles
>   destiné à un public déterminé pour l'amener à prendre une décision sur
>   un sujet particulier.

Le pluriel [est](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/livre_blanc) bel et bien : ***livres blancs***.

Answer (score 1):

En anglais cela s'appelle *(a) white paper* :

"A white paper is an authoritative report or guide informing readers in a concise manner about a complex issue and presenting the issuing body's philosophy on the matter. It is meant to help readers understand an issue, solve a problem, or make a decision.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_paper

> Un livre blanc au sujet du piratage.